# iOS8 Background App Refresh - disable "Use Cellular Data" setting by default

Tags: ios, download, settings, nsuserdefaults, nsurlsession

I have an app that has `remote-notification` enabled in the apps `UIBackgroundModes`. As I have discovered some days ago, iOS8 automatically adds options to enable and disable the automatic background fetch. Awesome! That way everything is handled by the system. Since my app downloads quite an amount of data (it's a newspaper app) in the background, I would love to disable the Cellular Data option by default, but let the option for hard core users to opt-in.

Of course I could implement this in my settings pane as well. Though this doesn't make a lot of sense in my opinion: The user might get confused, wondering, what is the correct setting?

So does anyone know, how to disable "use cellular data" by default?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to change that value. You could try to teach the user how to do it or as you mentioned, build the setting inside your app.